# Find the area of the region in $X$-$Y$ plane: $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x^2+y^2 \leq 144; \quad \sin(2x+3y) \leq0 \}$

Tags: area

$x^2+y^2=12^2$ is a circle having centre at $(0,0)$ & radius $12$. So,I could easily mark the first inequality.

But $\sin(2x+3y)=0$ implies $2x+3y=n(\pi)$ where $n$ is any integer
For $n=0$, $2x+3y=0$ & the graph is a straight line **passing through origin** and is easy to plot. But for **other values of $n$**, I'm unable to plot the graph and thus being unable to find the area.

Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: Suppose you've plot $y=-\frac{2}{3}x$. Then $y=-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}\pi n$ is a line $y=-\frac{2}{3}x$ lifted up by $\frac{2}{3}\pi n$ units. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2By%5E2%E2%89%A4144+%26%26+sin%282x%2B3y%29%E2%89%A40

Comment: @Alexey Burdin:Yes.No problem when **n=0**,but when n=any other value say **2** then how to mark **(4/3)pi** without a graphing calculator,& how to find the area at the end.can you please explain.

Comment: Why do so many people hate to put spaces after their punctuation?  I see this dozens of times a day - not just as an isolated typo once or twice in a post, but many users do this as a rule.

Comment: @Number: the values of $\pi, e, \ln 2$,etc usually are plotted aproximately. Nevertheless, plot doesn't look nice, see the link above. The area is $1/2$ area of the disc i.e. $\frac{12^2\pi}{2}$. Guess why. :)

Comment: @GregoryGrant one can start a meta post on this topic. If it were in the top, people would mind these spaces. :))

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you, not sure how to do that tho... I'll investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every point $X(x,y)$ inside the circle we specify another point $Y(-x,-y)$. Such, that $\sin(2x+3y)\le 0$ for $X$, $\sin(-2x-3y)\ge 0$ for $Y$ and vice versa.
$f(X)=Y$ is one-to-one except $(0,0)$, so all the points are divided in two sets with equal area (indeed, applying $f$ is flipping across $x+y=0$) with intersection area $0$, so each occupy $1/2$ of the area of the disc.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit complex for me. But now i think i've understood it. Thank you sir.